# How to add scroll bar to list view for my code?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, web-applications

Here above i have added my list view and i am beginner for web application so please help me to find out?

```
 <td class="auto-style11">
   <asp:HiddenField ID="hfSelectedRecord" runat="server" />
   <table id="tblCurrencyName" frame="border"  style="border: thin double #990033; margin-left: 117px;">
         <tr class="altRow">
            <td class="auto-style31">
                <b>Sno</b>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style30">
                <b>Currency Name</b>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style30"><b>Action</b></td>
         </tr>
         <asp:ListView ID="lstViewCurrencyName" OnItemCommand="lstViewCurrencyName_ItemCommand" runat="server" >
         <ItemTemplate>
            <tr class="<%#(Container.DataItemIndex+1)%2==0?" altrow":"normalrow"%>">
                 <td>
                      <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1%>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                      <%#Eval("CURRENCY_NAME") %>
                 </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ListView` should show a **Vertical Scrollbar** if you set the height for your control.

And, if you need the both Scrollbars wrap your `ListView` using a `DIV` tag as follows (And, note the `style` and height attributes of the DIV tag). In this case don't set `height` for your `ListView`.

```
<div style="height:350px; overflow:scroll">
<asp:ListView ID="lstViewCurrencyName" OnItemCommand="lstViewCurrencyName_ItemCommand" runat="server" >


...

</div>
```

Hope this helped!